# How to handle onAllComplete event when Uploading and Reading files?

Tags: jquery, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader and I can select files and send them to the server.

One of the things I use is the onAllComplete event, which is triggered when all files are sent to the server and I perform a series of actions.

My problem is that when reading the files that are previously being saved, this event is triggered, causing the actions I previously mentioned to fail.

Is there a way to detect that I am reading files and not sending them? Or perhaps there is another way to know when all the files have been sent to the server.

To read the files, I do it with:

```
session: {
    endpoint: 'my_php_file.php', 
    params: { acc: 'leer_xxx', id: 123 }
},
```

It reads them and puts them in the component, but it triggers onAllComplete, which I want to avoid.